# Inserting dates into MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, jpa, eclipselink

When doing JUnit tests I have to insert values into the database. For doing this I have a file (import.sql) which contains various inserts for various tests. It works perfect expect for dates. How would I have to format dates so that MySQL would be able to import them as dates.

The java entity

```
import java.util.Date;

@Entity
@Table(name = "TEST")
public class Test {

    @Column(name = "START")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date startDate;

    @Column(name = "END"
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date endDate;

    // getter & setter
}
```

Snippet from the import.sql

```
INSERT INTO TEST (START, END) VALUES ('2015-07-20 22:00:00.000', '2015-07-20 23:30:00.000')
INSERT INTO TEST (START, END) VALUES ('2015-08-18 21:00:00.000', '2015-08-18 22:30:00.000')
```

In this case `2015-08-18 21:00:00.000`, but this doesn't work. It results in an error telling that the format isn't correct.

Loading from import.sql

```
<property name="javax.persistence.sql-load-script-source"
        value="import.sql" />
```

How has the date be formatted?

Comment: Just use '2015-07-20 22:00:00', so stript the fraction of the seconds from the end.

Comment: @Shadow thanks a lot. It worked. You may want to post it as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use '2015-07-20 22:00:00', so stript the fraction of the seconds from the end if you are not using them any way. Fractional second support has been added in v5.6.4, so you may have compatibility issues if you have earlier versions.

Answer (score 2):

To match input value `2015-08-18 21:00:00.000`, the `START` field and `END` field type should be `DATETIME(3)`.

Comment: Thanks. This works but I prefer the solution from @Shadow as it's easier